# Statement about Woodall primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

A Woodall number is an integer of the form $n 2^{n}-1$.

A Woodall prime is an integer that is both a prime and a Woodall number.

Let $p$ be a prime of the form 1 mod 4.

Then $p 2^{p} -1$ is never a ( Woodall ) prime.

How to prove this ?

Comment: Just a try - p is of form 1 mod 4, now let's look on 2^p. when p>2, 2^p will always be 0 mod 4 (because 4 is 2^2 and by rules of power it divides with other powers of 2 without remainder). So if we multiply p with 2^p the result will be 0 mod 4. in addition, (-1) mod 4 is 3, so if you add both numbers, p*2^p - 1 mod 4 would be 3. meaning, it's divided by 4 with remainder of 3, but divided with 3 without remainder. which means it can't be a prime because 3 is one of his factors

Comment: Take p=13. 13 = 1 mod 4. Now (13 2^13 - 1)/5 is an integer but it is not a multiple of 3. So your argument fails ??

Comment: Consider only 13*2^13 - 1, without /5. Because this problem asks about woodal primes in this form

Comment: never mind. you're right

Comment: $n$ such that $n2^n-1$ is prime are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A002234